# Tensorflow DNN model in text: sparse matrix length is ambiguous

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

I'm new for tensorflow, and I want to build a model by text document.

I try use tensorflow example to build a DNN model and put bag of words feature to it.

Build feature by sklearn.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(content, label, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
count_vect = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 1), min_df=1, tokenizer=tokenize)
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X_train)

tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
```

Try tensorflow feature.

```
# Specify that all features have real-value data
feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("x", shape=[X_train_tfidf.shape[1]])]

# Build 3 layer DNN with 10, 20, 10 units respectively.
classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                          hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                                          n_classes=2,
                                        model_dir="/tmp/chinese_model")

train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"x": X_train_tfidf},
    y=np.array(y_train),
    num_epochs=None,
    shuffle=True)

classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=2000)
```

Error Message:

> TypeError: sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz() or shape[0]

Can someone help me out to fix it? Thanks you!

Comment: Is there a reason that you're using sklearn? I would instead use Tensorflow to build an embedding of the words.

Comment: @finbarr Thanks you for your replay! Do you have some great tutorial about embedding of the word?

Comment: Yes, I would recommend something like this: http://www.wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/